# Is it possible to generate html files from javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a question about html and javascript. I'm trying to find out if we can generate html files from javascript.

I want to implement a dynamic form in which a user makes choices like entering a question and answer. At the end, I would have an html file in which I have a form with the user's choices.

With Javascript, I know that I can create a dynamic form but is it possible to write it to a file?

Comment: what do you mean, "html file"? A file you can pop up a "save" dialog for? HTML is just text, and javascsript can generate any text you want...

Comment: How do you plan to save the file with javascript?

Comment: Why would you want the user's responses in a form? Typically you would store them in some kind of database.

Comment: So, what you're really asking (from what I can tell) is whether you can generate any generic file with JavaScript (and presumably prompt the user to save it to their local machine?), and you'll just happen to put HTML content into it.

Comment: «*At the end, I have a html file in which I have a form with users's choices*»—You want to generate a local file in the user's computer? And how exactly do you plan to read it later?

Comment: Yes, I want to generate a local file. If you want, I propose to the user to do some choices (the idea is that at the end, I have a html file in which I have a form with user's question). The main idea is the creation of exercises and the teacher chooses the question which he wants to ask.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care about older browsers you can take a look at this article http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/filesystem/

You can try and store the content you need in a session or cookie or even local storage for a more wide browser support.

As mentioned in the article:

> At the time of writing this article, Google Chrome has the only working implementation of the FileSystem API.

You can also add a server side API that will listen to your javascript and create the files (if you want the files to be stored on your server). For this you can check some implementations like http://extplorer.sourceforge.net/

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, here you have an example:

```
var html = '<!DOCTYPE html>'
    +'<html>'
    +'<head>'
        +'<title>Title</title>'
    +'</head>'
    +'<body>'
        +'<p>Content</p>'
    +'</body>'
    +'</html>',
    params = 'data:text/html;charset=UTF-8';
if(window.btoa){
    params += ';base64';
    html = window.btoa(unescape(html));
}
window.open(params + ',' + html);
```

If you run this code you will generate an html file and open it using data URIs!

Comment: Just I'm okey with your code but can you develop when you say "open it using date URis!" please

Comment: @A.F.K [Data URI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_Uri) is a way to include data in-line in web pages as if they were external resources. In this case, it can be used to open a webpage in a new tab from its html source code.

Comment: it's 2016 and we now have multiline string support via Template Strings. You should look into it.